# Unable to open project

Tags: qgis, error

I recently got a virus in my computer and, after having that fixed, was unable to open my Quantum GIS project.  I received an error message:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
Program: C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.exe
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I then clicked "okay" and it kicked me out of qgis.
I uninstalled qgis and reloaded it (version 1.8.0).  When I tried to open my project, I got the same message.  Then I opened qgis desktop and tried to open the project.  I got a message that said `Exception - Bad allocation`.

I need help.  I have to recover my project.

Comment: How was the virus fixed? Virus scan software or something else?

Comment: can you install QGIS on another machine or partition and try to open it? will QGIS open other projects?

Comment: I re-created the project (shapefiles all seem to be fine).  Then I saved it under a new name and it seems to open fine.